# How to access empty parameters passed to a parametrized job in a Jenkins Build step?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job with several parameters whose values are used to update database fields. Those parameter are "Active Choices Reactive Parameters" with type "Formatted HTML" and are rendered as input type "text".

Issue is that if one of those parameter is empty, even if its name appears in the "Environment variables" section of the build result, it is not availaible as an environment variable during build.

**Active choice Reactive Parameter**

Name: MY_FIRST_PARAM

Script: Groovy Script

Groovy Script:

```
// Unrelevant code above

if (field_value == 'null') {
    field_value = ''
}

// Parameter input rendering 
return "<input name=\"value\" value=\"${field_value}\" class=\"setting-input\" type=\"text\">"
```

**Build Step: Execute shell script**

This doesn't return anything

```
echo "$(env | grep 'MY_FIRST_PARAM')"
```

**Build result: Environment variables**

Even if parameter is listed in Environment variables, it is not available in previous buil step 'Execute shell script':

```
MY_FIRST_PARAM
```

As I need to perform some database query depending if job parameter has a value or is empty, how can I access its name from a build step if its value is empty?

Note that I tried to use null at first instead of an empty value but this generate an expection like:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

> Null value not allowed as an environment variable: MY_FIRST_PARAM

Comment: how do yoy pass the value that user enters in  the text box  to the job as a parameter? I´m trying to do that and unable to find the way using active choice reactive reference parameter.

Comment: @Chanafot: Not sure what you mean by "pass the value to the job as parameter" each input exposed to the user is itself a job parameter referenced by a unique variable in Jenkins Job. Active choice reactive parameter dynamically generate a list of values for a job parameter based on user action.See docs: https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/